# Permission denied to tempfile.mkdtemp()

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, temp

To test a program I'm creating a temporary directory to store the output. The first part creates the text file. The second part alters the text file. At the final line, I get a the following error:

`[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\matth\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmph8a9kuxh'`

**Code:**

```
tempdir =  tempfile.mkdtemp()
args = (
'python',
_EXECUTABLE,
'configure',
'--arg-one',
'ARGONE',
tempdir,
'-c',
str(pathlib.Path(tempdir)/'output.txt'),
'--force',
)
print(tempdir)
subprocess.run([x for x in args], check = True)

args = (
'python',
_EXECUTABLE,
'add',
'--node',
'NODE',
'-c',
str(pathlib.Path(tempdir)/'actions.txt'))
subprocess.run([x for x in args], check = True)
```

Comment: And `type(tempfile)`?

Comment: @uprego, tempfile is a library

Comment: Can't reproduce. I think it works at my end.

Comment: Good to know then; might be a permissioning thing. I'll try on a different machine.

Comment: An alternative, mostly recommended approach, is to provide a "minimal reproducible example".